# What files should be committed to github for an eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, git, github, egit

What files should I commit to github so that its a valid Eclipse project ?

I am just committing my source files and packages but when I try to re-create the project I receive this error 'no projects found' :

[image]

I think I need to also commit the .project file ?

Comment: Each Eclipse project has different layout (Web, Standalone etc). So the question is what Eclipse project you are dealing with. Then customize your `.gitignore` file accordingly. The `.project` file should be versioned in any case

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to commit your:

- `.settings` dir
- `.classpath` file
- `.project` file

The better idea will be to use maven for your project so that 
you will have a common configuration for all the IDEs (eclipse, netbeans, ideaj ...) and no need to push your eclipse specific configuration.

Answer (score 4):

For a typical Java SE Eclipse project, you must commit .project and .classpath files, but not necessary .settings folder. I tested this scenario by committing one project from my windows environment and cloning that onto my Linux environment; Eclipse imported and run this project without any error. Hope this tip helps you reduce committing one folder (the .setting).